# How to wait for an element has text to present?

Tags: playwright-java

I am expecting one locator to have to value Individual. But it is taking slight delay in getting value ..

I saw this in Typescript..

```
const locator = page.locator('my locator')
await expect(locator).toHaveValue('Individual', {timeout: 20000})
```

But what is similar to Java. Already i am in a frame and i am looking for one value customer type should be Individual..

```
        page1.frameLocator("iframe").locator("//*[@text='Last name']/..//input").fill("Auto Newpage");
        page1.frameLocator("iframe").locator("//*[@text='First name']/..//input").fill("Auto Newcontext");
        page1.frameLocator("iframe").locator("text=Save").click();
        page1.frameLocator("iframe").getByText("Identification", new FrameLocator.GetByTextOptions().setExact(true)).click();
        page1.frameLocator("iframe").getByRole(AriaRole.LINK, new FrameLocator.GetByRoleOptions().setName("General")).click();
        page1.frameLocator("iframe").locator("//*[@text='ip.identificationDetails.labels.ipType']/../static-control/p");
```

How to wait for this locator //*[@text='ip.identificationDetails.labels.ipType']/../static-control/p tohaveValue or tohaveText to present as Individual.. just because of slight delay it is returning empty every time. how to overcome and wait for an value and get that text?